# How are VIX options priced in a mean-reverting framework?

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, vix

If a trader assumes that the VIX follows a mean-reverting process like the Orstein-Uhlenbeck process, how would they price this non-martingale asset? My intuition tells me a trader would use doob-decomposition to find the other process to hedge with and replicate the VIX option that way, but am not sure